# Is there a command to remove moving blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm an admin on a friend's Realm and we get the usual hacker. They all use nbt data and I know what nbt data uses and it's **tile.moving_block.name**. I was wondering if there is a command to remove it from player's inventory because it's getting annoying.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "moving blocks"?

Comment: When hackers have tile.moving_block.name in there inventory cus they use those for hacks

Comment: Do you have any resources as to what they are?